# issue with 'first-child' selector in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .hori {
    color:red;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#car :first-child').addClass('hori');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="car">
        <li>Honda
            <ul>
                <li>Jazz</li>
                <li>Freed</li>
                <li>CRV</li>
                <li>Oddesey</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Nissan
            <ul>
                <li>Grand Livina</li>
                <li>Livina X-gear</li>
                <li>X-Trail</li>
            </ul>
        </li>       
        <li>Toyota
            <ul>
                <li>Fortuner</li>
                <li>Prius</li>
                <li>Innova</li>
            </ul>       
        </li>       
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Question:

I want to put class:hori(make red color) to this list:

```
        <li>Honda
            <ul>
                <li>Jazz</li>
                <li>Freed</li>
                <li>CRV</li>
                <li>Oddesey</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

So I use `$('#car :first-child').addClass('hori');`But the output is not what I want. Except Nissan and Toyota, all the texts turns into red color. so what is wrong with the css selector code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#car :first-child` selects *every* element that is a first child of anything within the `#car` element.

To select only the first `<li>` use this instead:

```
$('#car > :first-child').addClass('hori');
```

The `>` will make sure only to select a *direct* descendant of `#car`.

Of course, you don't really need jQuery as this can be done in CSS as well.

Comment: well, you are right, but according to here:http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/, it is said: Description: Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent. For `$('#car :first-child').addClass('hori');`,This is my thought: parent element is `<ul id="car">`, so the first child of `<ul id="car">`should be `<li>Honda`, the class 'hori' should be added only to `<li>Honda`,what is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: It also says: *"While :first matches only a single element, the :first-child selector can match more than one: one for each parent."* There are several elements within `#car` that have children, so `#car :first-child` will match *each* first child of any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell which first child exactly, please see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WCgP5/) , I have changed the html little bit

## html

```
<ul id="car">
    <li><span>Honda</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Jazz</li>
                <li>Freed</li>
                <li>CRV</li>
                <li>Oddesey</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <li><span>Nissan</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Grand Livina</li>
                <li>Livina X-gear</li>
                <li>X-Trail</li>
            </ul>
        </li>       
    <li><span>Toyota</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Fortuner</li>
                <li>Prius</li>
                <li>Innova</li>
            </ul>       
        </li>       
    </ul>
```

## css

```
.hori { color:red;}
.tori {color:green;}
.lori {color:blue;}
```

## js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#car li>:first-child').addClass('lori');
        $('#car >:first-child').addClass('hori');
        $('#car li > ul > li:first-child').addClass('tori');
});
```